# Outlook 2013 - remove date navigator from the To-Do Bar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

It appears that this might not be possible from here:  [Can you remove the date navigator from the Outlook 2013 To-Do bar?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/can-you-remove-the-date-navigator-from-the-outlook/f4b73ed3-7df1-4080-aa2e-5b6adf3434a7)

Basically I want to keep the To-Do bar for my tasks and would like the calendar appointment list itself to show up.  But I have no need for the date navigator itself.

Anyone know of a way to get this functionality back?  Or at least just provide this functionality even if it isn't with the To-Do bar.  I understand that this functionality was available in Outlook 2007, but it appears that 2013 did away with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not separate the calendar and upcoming appointments. You either have both or you have none. If you have dual monitor, you can turn off calendar and run a second instance of Outlook with a separate calendar on the other monitor.